# Apache POI - Invalid part to process data

Tags: java, apache-poi

I access an Excel spreadsheet using Java Apache POI (`hssf`). I got the following error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:143)
at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:426)
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)

Answer (score 9):

To [open](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook) an `xlsx` (Office Open XML) file, you should use [`XSSFWorkbook`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html) instead of [`HSSFWorkbook`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html), which is used for `xls` (Excel 97-2003) files.

If you are using POI < 3.5, you need to upgrade to at least version 3.5, in order to be able to read `xlsx` files. Here's a [guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html) for doing the conversion, but essentially, you'd need to load the file using [`WorkbookFactory`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create%28java.io.File%29) which takes care of the creation of either an `XSSFWorkbook` or `HSSFWorkbook` for you:

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("file.xlsx"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the excel sheet is not corrupt, by opening it.  If you seen any error, save the file as MS Excel 97-2003 Worksheet.
Also make sure you have specified the filename as "**.xls"