# Type mismatch: cannot convert from XSSFSheet to HSSFSheet

Tags: java

I am trying to read from an excel file using the below code:

```
    File file = new File("/C:/behzad-data/trp.small.xlsx");
    String dataPath=file.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println(dataPath);
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(file));

    //XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    HSSFRow row;
    HSSFCell cell;
```

but it complains with:

```
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:152)
```

so i have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844308/java-poi-he-supplied-data-appears-to-be-in-the-office-2007-xml), and make it like

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
 //   HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
```

but it complains with:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from XSSFSheet to HSSFSheet
```

How can i resolve both errors at the same time?

Comment: If you are using an older version of excel create a copy in save it as a newer format. If the reverse is true, do the reverse. Now use this new copy file.

Comment: i have tried `xlsx`, `xls` and `csv` none of them works

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12495381/898274)

Comment: I have tired the `XSSFWorkbook` but, it leads to the error. or if u mean `factory` please write an answer

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `WorkbookFactory`a nd only have to deal with one API for both types of workbooks? So with this new API, you don't have to prefex `Sheet`, `Row`, and so on with the file type, just use these classes like that.

```
File file = new File("C:\\behzad-data\\trp.small.xlsx");
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file);

Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
while (rows.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rows.next();
    // so on and so forth
}
```

Then just use `wb` as normal

Check the API docs for more info [HERE](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html)

**Note:** These dependencies are needed for this to work

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.16-beta2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.16-beta2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>3.16-beta2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: can u send a complete answer

Comment: Don't know if that is enough

Comment: `POIXMLException: Strict OOXML isn't currently supported, please see bug #57699`

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: I am really stumped, because I used the same thing to parse an excel file couple days ago. Probably do a clean and build and see if that helps, or delete and re-download the jars